# Async call never returns

Tags: multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

please have a look at below code.

```
public static class DbModel
{
        public static readonly int TableID = 0;

        static DbModel()
        {
            DbModel.PodID = FetchTableID().PodID;
        }

        public static Pod FetchTableID()
        {
            Pod result = null;
            try
            {                
        //Control never comes back from this line.  What am I missing?
                var searchResult = apiPod.SearchTableAsync(1).Result;
                result = searchResult.First();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.TraceException(PageName,"FEtchPodID","Unable to fetch PodID",ex);
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Signature of SearchTableAsync looks like this

```
public async Task<List<Pod>> SearchTableAsync(int i)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //deleted - connecting to server, constructing query string etc.

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(ApiBaseUrl + "api/Pod/Search" + queryString);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var podList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Pod>>();
                        return podList;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //log error
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.TraceError(null, ex);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Call to SearchTableAsync never returns back.  Am I missing anything?  Or its because I am invoking this from Static constructor?

Comment: What type of application is this? WinForms, WPF etc..

Comment: Its a WPF application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) post explains why it was blocking.
Cheers,
Hemant

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely due to the use of `Task.Result` property. this is a blocking property and can cause a [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). You can simply `await` the task which will return the result, but you need to make the method `async`.

```
    public static async Pod FetchTableID()
    {
        Pod result = null;
        try
        {                
            var searchResult = await apiPod.SearchTableAsync(1);
            result = searchResult.First();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.TraceException(PageName,"FEtchPodID","Unable to fetch PodID",ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

searchResult = apiPod.SearchTableAsync(1).excute.get;

use this instead of

var searchResult = apiPod.SearchTableAsync(1).Result;

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see any method/property named 'Execute' on SearchTableAsync(1) method call...

Comment: can u post ur method searchtableasync.